# SSH won't accept the public key

Tags: ssh, openssh

it's my first time seeing this error and was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this, i kept getting permission denied even though publickey is present.

```
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Apps/Documentum/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /Apps/Documentum/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
Connection closed
```

Comment: is your public key added to the server?

Comment: yes it is added.

Comment: id_rsa is the public key

Comment: `id_rsa` is the private key.  The contents of `id_rsa.pub` need to be present in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server.  Is that the case?

Comment: The id_rsa.pub is also present on the server.